# Custom Field on CMS Page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, cms-pages

How would I go about adding a custom field (image upload, specifically) to the CMS Page section? I'm looking to have a field where the client can upload an image, which then you can access it in a phtml file and call it in every cms page.

I've done this before in Magento 1 with a module, but not sure where to begin in Magento 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: U need to go to `vendor\magento\module-cms\view\adminhtml\ui_component\cms_page_form.xml` with take concept of  `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\category_form.xml` for Image Uploading. Can also refer http://webkul.com/blog/how-to-upload-image-in-magento2/